# Web Usage Statistics

Tags: statistics

What is a good site to check current web usage statistics -- particularly Java version, OS, browser. I have been trying to figure out Google Zeitgeist because it supposedly has this information, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Zeitgeist stopped providing that information back in '04 (or some time around then).

[W3Schools has some interesting data](http://w3schools.com/browsers/default.asp), but keep in mind that the audience that uses it is mostly developers, so it is more technically skewed.

Unfortunately, there is not a good source to get detailed browser/OS statistics on the web because it's considered private info by most sites.

Honestly, your best bet is to take statistics from your own site. You could use your server logs to do this, or you could use Google Analytics like others have mentioned. That can be used to record and view statistics about your site pretty nicely.

The reason you want to take statistics about your own site is because it is hard to say that the demographics that use one site or service will be the same as yours. If you take your own site's statistics, then you **know** who is using your site which is much more useful than general web statistics since user groups come in so many varieties depending on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Zeitgeist is more a gathering of statistics about searches on google. You're probably mistaking with [Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried www.google.com/analytics/?